# $\int_\Omega fd\mu_n\to\int_\Omega fd\mu,\ \forall\ f\in C_0(\Omega)$ implies $\mu_n(\Omega)\to \mu(\Omega)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open smooth domain and $C_0(\Omega)$ the set of bounded continuous functions with compact support. It is know that $C_0(\Omega)^\star =M(\Omega)$, where $M(\Omega)$ denotes the set of Radon measures (regular, bounded and infinitely additive). Suppose that $\mu_n\to \mu$ ($\mu_n,\mu\geq 0$) in the weak star sense, i.e. $$\int_\Omega fd\mu_n\to\int_\Omega fd\mu,\ \forall\ f\in C_0(\Omega)$$

Is it true that $\mu_n(\Omega)\to \mu(\Omega)$?

Thank you

Comment: PLease @DavideGiraudo, post your comment as an answer, so I can accpet it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Omega:=(0,1)$ and $\mu_n:=\delta_{n^{-1}}$, then we have the assumption with $\mu=0$, but not $μ_n(\Omega)=1\to \mu(\Omega)=0$.

One can generalize this taking $x\in \overline{\Omega}\setminus\Omega$ and $(x_n,n\in\Bbb N)\subset \Omega$ converging to $x$.